# When my location changes it adds another marker but doesn't remove the previous one

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, location, google-maps-markers

I am using the code below to check for current location of the device. and whenever it changes or refreshes the location it adds a marker without removing the last one. how can I remove the previous marker.

```
 if(locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)){
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, new LocationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                double latitude = location.getLatitude();
                double longtitude = location.getLongitude();
                LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longtitude);
                mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title("You Are Here"));
                mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 10.2f));
            }

            @Override
            public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {
            }
        });
    }
```

or is there another way of getting current location? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this**

Declare marker object as local

```
 private Marker currentMarker;
```

Do as follows:

```
if(locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)){
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, new LocationListener() {
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        if(currentMarker!=null){
        currentMarker.remove();
        }
        double latitude = location.getLatitude();
        double longtitude = location.getLongitude();
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longtitude);
        currentMarker=mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title("You Are Here"));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 10.2f));
        }

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {
        }

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {
        }

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {
        }
        });
        }
```

Comment: @FrancisVelasco  this way is better if you don't want to remove other markers. This will remove only the location marker. I'm using this and it works great. I'd have posted this if using desktop.

Comment: @FrancisVelasco. ..I was using the same method. Glad it helped.

Answer (score 0):

Save the maker object which is returned by the addMarker method, then you can use marker.setPosition to set the new position of the marker

Answer (score 0):

What actually happens is that whenever locationchanged is called, new marker is placed but actually before placing this marker, you should clear the map.
You should use this `mMap.clear();` as in the following code. 
`public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
mMap.clear();
double latitude = location.getLatitude(); double longtitude = location.getLongitude(); LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longtitude); mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title("You Are Here")); mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 10.2f)); }`
This way, map will be cleared and other markers  will also be removed. 
Answered through app, sorry for formatting, will edit later.